# How to play avi video using GStreamer

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to play my first video in GSTreamer, by using GstElement, without pre-configured things like `gst_parse_launch` etc

- I dont understand why my pipeline cant be linked and I get an error "unable to set the pipeline to playing state" ?
- How can I fix it? What is missed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int   argc,    char *argv[])
{
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source, *sink;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv); //! Initialize GStreamer

    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("my-pipeline"); //! Creating pipeline

    source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "file-source"); //! Creating source
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "location", "file:///D:/workspace/rocket.mp4", NULL);

    sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink"); //! Creating sink
    if (sink == NULL) 
    {
        g_error("Could not create neither 'autovideosink' element");
    }

    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, sink, NULL); //! Adding elements to pipeline container

    
    if (!gst_element_link_many(source, sink, NULL))  //! Linking all elements together
    {
        g_warning("Unable to link elements!");
    }

    auto ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING); //! Turning pipeline in PLAYING STATE

    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) 
    {
        g_printerr("unable to set the pipeline to playing state");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an answer**

First of all, here is [github link](https://github.com/Timino/GStreamer-examples-and-samples/blob/main/simple_avi_player.cpp) to my solution with comments.

---

Explanation:

If you want to play video file, without predefined pipelines, like `playbin`, `gst_parse_launch` etc, you have two options

1. Dynamically link `uridecodebin` with 2 pipeline sleeves (one for audio and second for video)
2. Dynamically link by using `avidemux` and make it on 'atomic' level. Its very complicated, and there is no working help in net. Maybe I will update this branch later with working solution.

In my github link, you will find first solution with 2 pipelines and `uridecodebin`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "file:///D:/workspace/rocket.mp4" to "D:/workspace/rocket.mp4".
And also maybe you need to change gst_element_link_many(source, sink, NULL) to gst_element_link(source, sink).